# d3js, detect click above chart

Tags: d3.js, svg, click

I have a grouped column chart built with d3.js v4. When the user clicks on a single chart, the other ones will become less visible to highlight the clicked chart. Now I have an usability issue: when the chart is very short, it's a little bit too hard to click on it, so I'd like to detect the click on all the section above the chart.

```
function onSelectSingleBarChart(d, i, j) {...
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dadnxjue/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to

- Add a transparent rectangle over each group chart so that it consumes the click.
- On click of the transparent bar call the `onSelectSingleBarChart` just as you were doing on individual bar chart

  `grp.append("rect")
  .attr("y", function(d) {return y(y.domain()[1]);})
  .attr("width", x0.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", y.domain()[1])//max domain
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return "transparent";
  })
  .on("click", onSelectSingleBarChart);`

working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/us90dv4w/1/)